# How can I use natbib package with ieeeconf style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I want to use `ieeeconf` as document class and include `natbib` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\usepackage{natbib}
% something here

\bibliography{reference}
```

I have provided my references in `reference.bib` file.
but I get error while compiling with pdflatex and TexWorks.

When I exclude the line:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I can compile it but what I see in pdf format is:

> [Alouani and Rice(1994)]

instead of

> [[1]]

In the text where I used `\cite{c1}`

and:

> [Aluni and Rice(1994)] A. T. Alouani and T. R. Rice. On asynchronous data fusion. pages143-146, 1994*

in the reference section. But what I want is to sort them in numbers format.

Here is one of my `.bib` file's item:

```
@article{c1,
author = {A. T. Alouani and T. R. Rice},
title = {On asynchronous data fusion},
booktitle = {Southeastern Symposium on System Theory},
year = {1994},
pages = {143--146},
masid = {50009577}
}
```

Please help me cope with this.

Comment: Use the `numbers` option of `natbib`,i.e., `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: Also IEEE has its own style for this class and you can use it via `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}\bibliography{reference}`

Comment: @Guido I can not use that package as I get error compiling

Comment: @batistacori It works for me. What is the error message? remove all auxiliary files, `.aux`, `.log`, `.bbl`.

Comment: error while reading aux file. even after deleting aux file and rebuild it

Comment: @percusse Your suggestion worked out. But I still don't have `\citet` command for citing et al.

Comment: @batistacori Yes IEEE doesn't support `natbib` package but requires only `\cite` command. So you can't use it with IEEE. It has its own standards (quality is questionable but that's the way it is). You can only use `cite` package for consecutive citations with `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` to get citations like `[1-7]` etc.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed? I know many people using natbib that are very frustrated that they cannot use it with IEEETran.

Comment: I found IEEETranN.bst that is exactly what I was looking for: http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtranN.bst

Comment: I don't think this should be closed either.  how does a question that's too narrow accrue 1000 views?  fwiw, `IEEETranN` solved the problems I was having.

Comment: Replacing the call to ieeeconf with IEEEtran was necessary to fix my issues. The result looks like `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} ... \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{references}`